# MySQL IF on Where clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause

Is it possible to make a query that changes the where clause acording to some condition? For instance I want to select * from table1 where data is 19/July/2016 but if field id is null then do nothing, else compare id to something else. Like the query bellow?

```
Select * from table1 where date="2016-07-19" if(isnull(id),"",and id=(select * from ...))
```

Comment: OK, I see the two answers, one mine, have interpreted what you want in different ways.  So, you might want to edit the question to clarify what you meant by "do nothing".

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This should be possible.

If we assume that **`date`** and **`id`** are references to *columns* in (the unfortunately named) table **`table1`**, if I'm understanding what you are attempting to achieve, we could write a query like this:

```
 SELECT t.id
      , t.date
      , t.... 
   FROM table1 t 
  WHERE t.date='2016-07-19' 
    AND (  t.id IS NULL
        OR t.id IN ( SELECT expr FROM ... )
        )
```

It would also be possible to incorporate the MySQL `IF()` and `IFNULL()` functions, if there's some requirement to do that.

As far as dynamically changing the text of the SQL statement after the statement is submitted to the database, no, that's not possible. Any dynamic changes to the SQL text would need to be done when the SQL statement is generated, *before* it is submitted to the database.

My personal preference would be to use a join operation rather than a `IN (subquery)` predicate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying too hard.  If id is `NULL` that's equivalent to having a `FALSE` in the where clause.  So:

```
Select * from table1 where date="2016-07-19" and id=(select * from ...)
```

Should only match the records you want.  If `id` is `NULL` you get nothing.